# "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length" error, even if comment has 15 symbols

Tags: discussion, bug, character-limit

[image]

You can see gray text "585 characters left" ('cause looks like the comment has 15 symbols). But if you try to send it, you will get error.

It's because of the space symbol in the begging. So, here is the problem:

1. 1st step validator count space as a valid symbol.
2. But second validator (after pressing send), obviously, doesn't count spaces, so we get this error.

It's misleading a little bit. If spaces doesn't count, the error message should be shown in gray text too.

[image]